# Removing spaces between words in a text file using a bash script

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am using a bash script that parses data from a bunch of different text files and generates a .dts file. The .dts file contains spaces between each column title and I need to remove them as it makes a plotting tool I use crash. See below for example:

```
Avg Interval Time           Interval Num        Total pts         Avg Delta Time
```

I need it to look like this (There are spaces between each column title)

```
AvgIntervalTime           IntervalNum        Totalpts         AvgDeltaTime
```

Can the sed command perform this function? The above is all in Line 1 of the .dts file.

FSA, I have done some research on the sed command and i can only find examples of how to remove leading/trailing edge spaces or all the spaces, but nothing to just remove spaces between certain words.

Comment: a) Are the spaces between column titles also blank characters or are they tabs? If they're blanks b) is each column a fixed width or not? c) is there guaranteed to be 2 or more blanks between titles and never more than 1 blank within a title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few scripts:

- `sed 's/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/\1\2/g'` When the words are separated by one space and the columns are separated by tabs or multiple spaces. Edit: Please see [@steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1504186/1004020) for a better version of this script
- `sed '1s/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/\1\2/g'` First line only
- `tr -d ' '` Remove all spaces
- `sed 's/Avg \+Interval \+Time/AvgIntervalTime/;s/Interval \+Num/IntervalNum/;s/Total \+pts/Totalpts/;s/Avg \+Delta \+Time/AvgDeltaTime/'` Manually specify the words and remove any number of spaces

Pipe the .dts file to the sed command, then redirect to a new file or use `-i` with `sed <expr> <filename>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match a *single space* occurring *between word characters*, you can anchor it with `\b`:

> \b
>
> Matches a word boundary; that is it matches if the character to the left is a
> “word” character and the character to the right is a “non-word” character,
> or vice-versa.

So for example

```
$ cat file
Avg Interval Time           Interval Num        Total pts         Avg Delta Time

$ sed 's/\b \b//g' file
AvgIntervalTime           IntervalNum        Totalpts         AvgDeltaTime
```